# Is there a way to get the Type by full name using Go reflection?

Tags: go

In Java, it can be done by `Class.forName("com.my_pkg_name.MyClass")` which returns the class type.

It seems Go reflection can only find the Type by Value but doesn't allow name to Type. This capability can be very helpful when implementing a scripting language interpreter which interops with Go code.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible. The `reflect` package does not provide a function like `TypeByName(name string)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not unless you explicitly register the type, like the [`gob`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/#Register) package does. Something like

```
// NOTE Should be protected by a mutex.
var types map[string]reflect.Type

func Register(value interface{}) {
    t := reflect.TypeOf(value)
    name := t.PkgPath() + "." + t.Name()
    types[name] = t
}

func TypeByName(name string) reflect.Type {
    return types[name]
}
```